# Store user information in json or in a table in a database?

Tags: json, storage, message

I'm developing a site that has to store a user's contact list. So it will contain people's phone numbers, addresses and also messages sent to this contact. I obviously want to keep this information secure but it seems quite easy an efficient just giving each user a json file with an array of details.
I'm not too sure if this is a horrendously dangerous and insecure idea and if I should be using a table in a database, or something else. Using a table to store messages sent between users doesn't seem too intuitive though. So I was just wanted to know what the most sensible way I would store
i) User specific contact lists with sensitive information
ii) Messages sent between two contacts
I'm sorry if this is a widely known and not even talked about topic. I just couldn't really find a clear answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use a database for this. If you store these values on files, then you will have to load all of the information per user every single time you need to access something as small as a single phone number.

Comment: would that be the main problem?  is there not a security issue? and what about messages between the two contacts, should I try to keep that on a databse?

Comment: I can also see plenty of security problems. Since you would be loading the JSON object with all of the data in the client, I could easily write an script to access data you probably meant to keep hidden from me. Also, how do plan on feeding these files, a CDN? How fast can you deserialize them into JSON objects?

Comment: Regarding the messages, you should definitely store them in a database. You will be able to perform paging on retrieval for example. 

This is a very strange architecture for a problem that has been solved multiple times using databases and secure frameworks. Is there any reason why you thought using files would be better than a database?

Comment: I assumed retrieving hundreds of messages from a database just to load up one conversation would be quite taxing on a server and also less time-efficient. Also I haven't used sql for anything more complex than a register-login system, instead I found an array of messages in a .json file is simple to edit, and iterate through. Nevertheless, it seems I'm gonna have to face the music and get cracking on this database. Thanks for the heads up!